# Is there any difference between manually adding a DbSet or allowing the table to be automatically created?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a type called `TypeA` and somewhere in `TypeA` there is a property of `TypeB` (which contains nothing other than an `ID` and `String`).

Using Entity Framework, I have created a `DbSet` of `TypeA` - `public DbSet<TypeA>`.

This creates the `TypeB` column in the database just fine - however, I now need to seed some data. As `TypeB` does not exist in the original `DbContext`, I am unable to seed data to it.

I therefore added `public DbSet<TypeB>` to my original `DbContext` and it didn't even detect a change/difference in the Database schema.

So, this got me wondering, and my question is, Is there any difference in creating a separate `DbSet` over one that is automatically created by a relation?

Sample Code

```
  public class TypeA
    {

        public int id { get; set; }


        public string name { get; set; }


        public TypeB foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class TypeB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

In design terms, the point of the [`DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class is [to embody the Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html):

> Conceptually, a Repository encapsulates the set of objects persisted in a data store and the operations performed over them, providing a more object-oriented view of the persistence layer. Repository also supports the objective of achieving a clean separation and one-way dependency between the domain and data mapping layers.

Its purpose is to encapsulate [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) for a given entity.  In order to do this the repository can't limit itself to just one table.  Sometimes it must work with an object tree in the DB.

In your case, having a [`DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for both types will give you a repository to directly access that entity.  This will allow you to query directly for `TypeB` or directly create/update `TypeB` instances in the DB, rather than always having to always root your queries in `TypeA`.

Some of this depends on your associations, though.  If you have a constraint on `TypeB` that requires a `TypeA`, then you can't create them without a `TypeA`.  However you can still query for them directly.

You can still create or update `TypeB` instances without the `DbSet<TypeB>` - simply attach one to the `TypeA` instance and work against the the `DbSet<TypeA>`.

Comment: This is great, thank you - As I said, I wasn't able to seed data (outside of defining it in a `TypeA`), but, after I created the `DbSet`, I was able to create the seed data just fine. So basically, you are saying apart from being able to access the data directly, there is no difference what so ever "internally"? ... I was just thrown when it didn't trigger an update/detect a schema change.

Comment: @William: That's right :) If you have a property defined on an entity that is a complex type, that data has to go somewhere.  The `DbSet<TypeA>` knows this, and creates the tables (and possibly constraints) it needs on the fly.